# I am trying to parse string from python regex-Not able get desired output

Tags: python, regex

```
sample_string = ":61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXC:OL3654628815//CT56748005:86:/BENM/Unitech Imports/REM//58970.047:61:2002190219C30000S103LCADV5674920204//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV:/FEB20/446301:61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628825//CT56748005:60F:61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628815//CT56748018"
```

Basically I need all

```
1. :61:, :86: string which are next to each other any where in the full message ex:- re.findall()=expected o/p - [':61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXC:OL3654628815//CT56748005:86:/BENM/Unitech Imports/REM//58970.047', :61:2002190219C30000S103LCADV5674920204//CT56748006:86:/BENM/Gravity Imports/REM//INV:/FEB20/446301] 
i have below regex for above case which is working fine, can we simplify a bit, 
61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*:86:(?:[A-Za-z0-9 /.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*
regex example - https://regex101.com/r/U3MWF7/4

2. All :61 string which are not followed by :86 anywhere in the full message, ex:- re.findall()=
expected o/p=[':61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628825//CT56748005',':61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628815//CT56748018']

I have below regex to get all :61 strings from message which is not giving correct result - its giving all :61 strings which are followed by:86 also.
61:(?:[\w /,.-]|:(?!61:|86:))*(?!:86:)* ()
regex example - https://regex101.com/r/2svNjG/1
```

I have tried multiple option but not able to get required output. request for help

Comment: Like this? `:61:(?!.*:86).*?(?=:61:|$)` https://regex101.com/r/zA9SFB/1 and https://regex101.com/r/iieEyg/1

Answer (score 2):

You can match :61: and assert that what is on the right does not contain :86: Then match until the next occurrence of :61: by matching either one of the listed in `[\w /.-]` or match a `:` not directly followed by `61:`

```
:61:(?!.*:86:)(?:[\w /.-]|:(?!61:)[\w /.-]*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cv3sva/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VQuU3j)

If there are multiple lines, you can make the dot match a newline using `re.DOTALL` or use an inline modifier `(?s)`

```
(?s):61:(?!.*:86:)(?:[\w /.-]|:(?!61:)[\w /.-]*)*
```

Comment: This is including :60F:, which is different string all together. :61:2002190219C45612.4S202EXCOL3654628825//CT56748005 **:60F:**

Comment: @Navneet So you don't want to include a 6 followed by a digit and optional char A-Z? https://regex101.com/r/DzoIcc/1 or a char a-z or digit https://regex101.com/r/Flrlq7/1

Comment: Not maching for full string https://regex101.com/r/Flrlq7/1

Comment: @Navneet What do you mean by full string? You get the 2 desired matches right?

Comment: check this regex101.com/r/Flrlq7/1 
 This should give 3, 61 messages as below [:61:2002190219C27975.75S202EXP.256/34//CT56748007,:61:2002190219D37000S103IMCOL3664550015//CT56748010, :61:2002190219D42385.5510075 //CT56748011 ]

Comment: @Navneet This will give you 3 matches `:61:.*?(?=:61:(?!.*:86:)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/N68fWl/1 Or `:61:.*?(?=:[A-Za-z0-9]+:(?!.*:86:)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/YpjD8V/1 or `:61:.*?(?=:6\d+[A-Z]?:(?!.*:86:)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/EHWxmz/1

Comment: @Navneet But these 3 strings are not present in https://regex101.com/r/Flrlq7/1

Comment: @ The fourth bird- Sorry for the confusion - string didnt update in link , I was checking given regex with another string(similar one )  https://regex101.com/r/Flrlq7/2 This should give 3, 61 messages as below [:61:2002190219C27975.75S202EXP.256/34//CT56748007,:61:2002190219D37000S103IMCOL3664550015//CT56748010, :61:2002190219D42385.5510075 //CT56748011 ]

Comment: @Navneet This will match those values `:61:(?:(?!:61:|:86:).)*(?=:(?!86:)[a-zA-Z0-9]+:)`  https://regex101.com/r/1pot04/1

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird , still some of string are not matching but you have given enough pointers. i will look in that  Thanks:)

Comment: @Navneet Ok, if you have any issues about these matches please share a full data example with the expected matches (and make sure that the expected strings are present in the example)

Comment: forth bird Sure, Thanks